# only show most used items in 'all programs'

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I'm not talking about the 'recent items' or 'recent used programs' in the start menu. I'm referring to the folders and programs under 'all programs'. I thought this was a feature in previous versions of windows, but does this still work under windows 7? (And if so, how can I activate that?)

Comment: Can you clarify, describing more about this feature? I found this [Microsoft Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1f2c96e3-5f76-40fb-a125-866902809997/start-menu-recently-used-programs-list-not-updated) article but as soon as I re-read your post I fail to understand clearly your question.

Comment: All Programs display all installed programs with a shortcut.  This feature was moved into recent items in the start menu.

Comment: @Doktoro Reichard : If my memory doesn't fail me (and maybe it does), I thought in the past the program folders under 'all programs' would show all the folders/programs that are available. UNLESS those programs hadn't been used in a long time, after which they pretty much would disappear. Hovering in the list would make the 'hidden' icons/folders appear.

Comment: @Malachi I'm using Windows XP and I can grant you that, as soon as I open the `All Programs`, a pile of junk (namely folders and shortcuts, most of which I haven't used for years) flood the area otherwise denominated as my screen. I don't even remember there being a feature such as that in Windows 98. What was is that whenever you installed a new program, the folder was tinted orange, but that also happens in Windows 7. Maybe you just had some desktop cleanup activated.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is NO, it does not work these way in Windows 7.

As it name describes, 'All programs' will always show all installed applications in your user, and if you only want to see the most used programs you should use the 'Recent programs' way.

You can configure the number of programs to show in the Star menu and task bar Properties -> Start menu tab -> Personalize button, and select the number of items you want to show when you open the Start menu.